# How to apply sequence function to List of ValidatedNel in cats?

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-cats

I have the following code

```
sealed trait DomainValidation {
  def errorMessage: String
}
type ValidationResult[A] = ValidatedNel[DomainValidation, A]
val ai:ValidationResult[String] = "big".validNel
val bi:ValidationResult[String] = "leboski".validNel
val l = List(ai,bi)
```

I want to convert `l` to `ValidationResult[List[String]]`. I came across `sequence` functionality but I am unable to use cats `sequence` as some implicit has to be there which knows how to handle `ValidationResult[A]`. But I am unable figure out what exactly is needed. I wrote the following

```
object helper {
  implicit class hello[A](l: List[ValidationResult[A]]) {
    def mysequence: ValidationResult[List[A]] = {
     val m = l.collect { case Invalid(a) => Invalid(a) }
     if (m.isEmpty) l.map { case Valid(a) => a }.validNel
     else /* merge the NonEmpty Lists */
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to do `l.mysequence`. But how do I use cats `sequence`.

PS: I am a scala beginner. Having a hard time learning :). Forgive for any incorrect mentions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work as expected on Scala 2.12:

```
import cats.data.ValidatedNel, cats.syntax.validated._

// Your code:
sealed trait DomainValidation {
  def errorMessage: String
}
type ValidationResult[A] = ValidatedNel[DomainValidation, A]
val ai:ValidationResult[String] = "big".validNel
val bi:ValidationResult[String] = "leboski".validNel
val l = List(ai,bi)
```

And then:

```
scala> import cats.instances.list._, cats.syntax.traverse._
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.syntax.traverse._

scala> l.sequence
res0: ValidationResult[List[String]] = Valid(List(big, leboski))
```

You don't show your code or explain what's not working, so it's hard to diagnose your issue, but it's likely to be one of the following problems:

1. You're on Scala 2.11, where `.sequence` requires you to enable `-Ypartial-unification` in your compiler options. If you're using sbt, you can do this by adding `scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"` to your `build.sbt` (assuming you're on 2.11.9+).
2. You've omitted one of the necessary imports. You need at least the `Traverse` instance for `List` and the syntax for `Traverse`. The example code above includes the two imports you need, or you can just import `cats.implicits._` and make your life a little easier.

If it's not one of these two things, you'll probably need to include more detail in your question for us to be able to help.

Comment: Thanks alot. Yes I am using Scala 2.11. And the error is intellij tries to look for some implicit but is unable to find it. It shows (..) in red marks.